# Google PageSpeed Insights Error on everything

Tags: pagespeed, google-pagespeed, pagespeed-insights

When I test our site with PageSpeed insights v5 i get Error! for all lab data and opportunities.

It also is telling me I have way more assets than there really is.

It is basically multiplying how many assets are really there by the number of products shown on the page.

We have an ecommerce website.

Any help or insight would be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The new PSI is a little buggy and overloaded since it came out, everyone is trying to jump in.

I suppose therefore you tested it on a website, try running it on a chrome lighthouse.

Also if you are using any caches, try to delete those in case those resources are left behind in the cache.

Cheers